# SqlServerTypes ARM64 .NET Parallels 'Error loading msvcr120.dll (ErrorCode: 193)'

Tags: .net, sql-server, arm64, parallels

I need to install and run a .NET framework for work using parallels.

When running the app using ARM64 I am getting an error

> Error loading msvcr120.dll (ErrorCode: 193)

The file does exists in the solution, however I realized it does not exist in the FrameworkArm64 folder but does exist on the Framework64 folder locally, not sure if it is required as it is in the solution.

Running the app in x64 or x86 just caused dependency issues.

**Solutions I have tried:**

- Reinstalling redistribution files.
- Copying the Microsoft folder in the FrameworkArm64 folder.
- running app in different configurations

** I am running SQL on the Mac side and connecting the SSMS via IP -- again not sure if this helps.

Comment: `msvcr120.dll` was a part of the [Visual C++ 2013 and Visual C++ Redistributable Package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/latest-supported-vc-redist#visual-studio-2013-vc-120). Do you think Microsoft will recompile it in 2023 for the ARM64 platform? Or do you think you could recompile your project with modern dependencies from VS2015 or later that already have ARM64 support?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning You mean downloading VS2015 and try running the app on that, rather than VS2022